# Use an argument from docker-compose build --build-arg inside a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, sed, docker-compose

I want to be able to build an image while replacing the `HOSTNAME` in my files automatically at build with the use of `sed`:

This my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ...            
RUN sed -i -- 's/0.0.0.0/$HOSTNAME/g' index.html
```

This is my command:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg HOSTNAME='justanotherhostname.com'
```

When I check the resulting `index.html`, my paths went from this:

```
path = 'http://0.0.0.0/'
```

to this:

```
path = 'http://$HOSTNAME/'
```

and not this:

```
path = 'http://justanotherhostname.com/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to introduce build argument also in Dockerfile (in case that was missing). Also if you want to replace `0.0.0.0` with the content of $HOSTNAME, you can try to enclose the sed command in double-quotes.

```
FROM ...
ARG HOSTNAME            
RUN sed -i -- "s/0.0.0.0/$HOSTNAME/g" index.html
```